# list Items from a map variable

Tags: c++, dictionary

I am just trying to get the values from a map variable. But for some reason its giving a   error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::operator<<  error. Here is a snippet of my code.

```
std::map <string, list<int> > gradeList;
....
gradeList.insert(std::make_pair("A", itemVal));
```

And after that I am trying to print it with a for loop

```
for(map<string, list<int> >::iterator it = gradeList.begin(); it != gradeList.end(); ++it) {
        cout << it->first << " " << it->second <<  "\n";
    }
```

Which is giving me error. Any idea what's going on ?

thanks

Comment: if 'second' is a list, you need to iterate that as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expression `it->second` has type `std::list<int>`. There is no `operator <<` overloaded for an object of type `std::list`. You have at least also to use a loop that to output elements of a list.

For example

```
for(map<string, list<int> >::iterator it = gradeList.begin(); it != gradeList.end(); ++it) {
        cout << it->first << ":";
        for ( int x : it->second ) cout << ' ' << x;
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You get an error because `it->second` is a `std::list` which doesn't have an overloaded output operator for it.

Answer (score 2):

`it->second` has type `std::list`.

`<<` is not overloaded for this .Hence the error.

If you want to print this, you can use a function of your own.

```
void print_list(std::list<int> a){
    for(auto i:a)
        std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
}
```